# LiveAgent giving 503 error

Tags: liveagent, chat, cors

Banging my head against a wall here.
I have enabled LiveAgent in my service cloud app. 
I have added a CORS setting
I have added the button to my website

Button is showing 'Chat with an expert' which is correct. I have logged in users in Salesforce ready to take chats.

Except when i click on Chat with an expert i get 2 console errors in Chrome. One is a 503 saying service unavailable, and one is a CORS error -

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Domain is in the CORS list in salesforce.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get a solve for this?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause, and what we faced, has to do with the **Site Endpoint** you choose in the **Embedded Service Deployments** configuration.  If the site is inactive, you will see the CORS error.  If it is a community you will probably see the CORS error unless you have the community configured for guest access (minimally).